# Python 3.5 urllib won't open webpage in browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, browser, urllib

I tried following code in VS2015, Eclipse and Spyder:

```
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.python.org/') as response:
    html = response.read()
```

In call cases it won't open the webpage in the browser. I am not sure what is the problem. Debug won't help. In VS2015 the program exists with code 0 which I suppose means successful.

Comment: For the record; exit code 0 usually indicates success (no errors occurred).

Comment: I know that and that's why I am confused. Debug does not yield anything. Maybe python is not able to call Chrome/IE browser.

Comment: Ohh, you want to show the page in web browser? Not download its contents? Can you clarify?

Comment: Firstly, I am a newbie. When I ran this code I was expecting the webpage to get displayed in the browser. I am working on an introductory code problem on reddit. https://www.reddit.com/r/beginnerprojects/comments/1jg2ru/project_random_wikipedia_article/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using wrong library for the job. `urllib` module provides functions to send http requests and capture the result in your program. It has nothing to do with a web browser. What you are looking for is the [`webbrowser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html) module. Here is an example:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('http://google.com')
```

This will show the web page in your browser.

Comment: Yeah! I did it! But without your comment I would not have realized it! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
urllib
```

is a module that is used to send request to web pages and read its contents.

Where as:

```
webbrowser
```

is used to open the desired url.

It can used as follows:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('http://docs.python.org/lib/module-webbrowser.html')
```

which usually re-uses existing browser window.

To open in new window:

```
webbrowser.open_new('http://docs.python.org/lib/module-webbrowser.html')
```

To open in new tab:

```
webbrowser.open_new_tab('http://docs.python.org/lib/module-webbrowser.html')
```

To access via command line interface:

```
$ python -m webbrowser -t "http://www.python.org"
-n: open new window
-t: open new tab
```

Here is python documentation for webbrowser:

[python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/webbrowser.html)

[python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/webbrowser.html)